# Как удалить localStorage в JSON?

Tags: javascript, json

Сохраняю переменную

```
localStorage.setItem('key', '{"board":["1","2","3","4"]}');
```

Как удалить элемент "2"?

Comment: `getItem` - получает из localStorage а не сохраняет в него.

Comment: Поправил, спасибо, но не суть. Вопрос про удаление

Comment: Во время сохранения - никак. Удаляй **до сохранения**. чтобы вызов был сразу `localStorage.setItem('key', '{"board":["1","3","4"]}');`

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Как удалить пункт 2 после сохранения из переменной key?

Comment: нужно загрузить, разобрать полученный Json, отфильтровать массив `board`, например, с помощью метода `filter` и записать обратно

Comment: кроме того в коде в вопросе нет никакой переменной key.

Answer (score 1):

Чет типо того:

```
let obj = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('key'))
obj['board'].splice(obj['board'].indexOf('2'), 1)
localStorage.setItem('key', JSON.stringify(obj))
```